# Android Parse Query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using the following iOS Parse query:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(fromUserid = %@ OR fromUserid = %@) AND (toUserid = %@ OR toUserid = %@) AND seen = %@", profilePhotoID, friendProfilePhotoID, profilePhotoID, friendProfilePhotoID, false)
var query = PFQuery(className: "Message", predicate: predicate)
```

How can I do the same query using the Parse Android SDK? I don't see an option to do predicates like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query data from parse in android SDK is like given example...

```
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Message");
        String[] ids = {profilePhotoID, friendProfilePhotoID};
        query.whereContainedIn("fromUserid", Arrays.asList(ids));
        query.whereContainedIn("toUserid", Arrays.asList(ids));
        query.whereEqualTo("seen",  false);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("Message", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " Message");
                } else {
                    Log.d("Message", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

For more details please refer [Parse Query Document](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries)

let me know if anything needed..